# connect to HP scanner using IP address from Jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I want to connect to HP scanner to scan documents from JSP page.I have the scanner IP address please help me anybody please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html) - Image Acquisition Framework for Java Platform available from [www.gnome.sk](http://www.gnome.sk). In version 6.2, it has common Api for Sane as well as for Twain interfaces. To acquire an image,sample is as shown:

```
//Select a twain driver
//MorenaSource source=TwainManager.selectSource(null);
//Or select a Sane driver
MorenaSource source=SaneConnection.connect("localhost").selectSource(null);
//From this point of code, it is independent if source is twain or sane:
Image image=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(source);
```

Hope this will head to right direction